# SQL Syntax error, expression of non-boolean type

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

This code is supposed to create a graph of revenue from money made through sales tickets at an event.

The code only executes up to `da.Fill(ds)` when it returns the error, which can be seen at the end of the code.

Does anybody know why

```
  Private Sub frmRevenue_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    frmMDI.addFormToCMS()

    Dim dt As DataTable
    dt = New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Fee")

    Dim sales As Integer = 0

    Dim gridtable As New DataTable
    gridtable.Columns.Add("Month")
    gridtable.Columns.Add("Total")
    gridtable.Columns.Add("#")

    For i = 1 To 12
        sql = "SELECT Fee FROM tblTickets WHERE MONTH(DatePurchased) = " & i & " AND (YEAR(DatePurchased) = " & Today.Year & " OR " & Year(Today.AddYears(1)) & ") AND (Status = 'SOLD' OR RESERVED" _
& " = 'AWAITING CONFIRMATION' OR Status = 'AVAILABLE' OR Status = 'AWAITING PAYMENT');"

        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)

        Dim dr As DataRow

        For Each dr In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            monthly(i) = monthly(i) + 1
            contracts = sales + 1
            total(i) = total(i) + dr.Item("Fee")
            yearlytotal = yearlytotal + dr.Item("Fee")
        Next
    Next

    For i = 1 To 12
        Dim month As String
        Select Case i
            Case 1
                month = "Jan"
            Case 2
                month = "Feb"
            Case 3
                month = "Mar"
            Case 4
                month = "Apr"
            Case 5
                month = "May"
            Case 6
                month = "Jun"
            Case 7
                month = "Jul"
            Case 8
                month = "Aug"
            Case 9
                month = "Sep"
            Case 10
                month = "Oct"
            Case 11
                month = "Nov"
            Case 12
                month = "Dec"
            Case Else
                month = "ERR"
        End Select

        gridtable.Rows.Add(month, FormatCurrency(total(i)), monthly(i))
    Next

    ugTickets.DataSource = gridtable
    ugTickets.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("Month").Width = 35
    ugTickets.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("#").Width = 20
    ugTickets.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowUpdate = DefaultableBoolean.False
    txtAnnual.ReadOnly = True
    txtAnnual.BackColor = Color.White
    txtAnnualContracts.ReadOnly = True
    txtAnnualContracts.BackColor = Color.White
    chRevenue.Titles("chTitle").Text = "Predicted revenue for " & Today.Year & " - " & Year(Today.AddYears(1))
    txtAnnual.Text = FormatCurrency(yearlytotal, 2)
    txtAnnualContracts.Text = contracts
    chRevenue.Series("Series1").Name = "Revenue"

    For i = 1 To 12
        chRevenue.Series("Revenue").Points.AddY(total(i))
    Next

    Try
        chRevenue.BackColor = Color.Transparent
        chRevenue.Legends("Revenue").BackColor = Color.Transparent
        chRevenue.Series("Revenue").ChartArea = "ChartArea1"
        chRevenue.Series("Revenue").Color = Color.SkyBlue
        chRevenue.Series("Revenue").ToolTip = FormatCurrency("#VALY", 2)
    Catch
    End Try

End Sub
```

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this bit of the SQL:

```
(YEAR(DatePurchased) = " & Today.Year & " OR " & Year(Today.AddYears(1)) & ")
```

It should probably be

```
(YEAR(DatePurchased) = " & Today.Year & " OR YEAR(DatePurchased) = " & Year(Today.AddYears(1)) & ")
```

The OR in SQL (and in most other languages) needs to have two independently valid conditions on each side. The left hand side currently looks like this:

```
YEAR(DatePurchased) = 2016
```

...which is fine. But the right looks like this:

```
2017
```

...which isn't a valid boolean.

When you get an error like this on the da.Fill() line (ie. the line that's actually running the SQL in the database), the easiest way to debug it is to print out the value of the "sql" variable.

Often, you can just look at the SQL it's generated and the problem will be obvious. Other times you have to copy it and run it directly against your database to see what the problem is.

Comment: and this part (Status = 'SOLD' OR Status = 'AWAITING CONFIRMATION' OR Status = 'RESERVED' OR Status = 'AVAILABLE' OR Status = 'AWAITING PAYMENT')

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b You might be right, but without seeing the table definition I don't know. The code as shown will produce valid SQL. It just depends on whether there is a column called RESERVED or not.

Answer (score -1):

Might be your SQL, try:

```
"SELECT Fee FROM tblTickets WHERE MONTH(DatePurchased) = '" & i &
"' AND (YEAR(DatePurchased) = '" & Today.Year & 
"' OR '" & Year(Today.AddYears(1)) & "') " & 
"AND (Status = 'SOLD' OR RESERVED = 'AWAITING CONFIRMATION' " &
                      "OR Status = 'AVAILABLE' " &
                      "OR Status = 'AWAITING PAYMENT');"
```